Scale free and anomalous regime other names
I have a system which examines clusters and percolation of these clusters (which is also a cellular automaton). Now, I have two critical power-law exponents in the regimes
$1<  \alpha  <2$ and $2<  \alpha  <3$ for the power law $x^\alpha$. In the first case, the power-law distribution has both an infinite mean and infinite variance, and in network theory, it's called the anomalous regime. In the second case, the power-law distribution has a finite mean and infinite variance, and is referred to as the scale-free regime. I am looking to see whether in cluster dynamics/percolation there is similar nomenclature for these exponents. I am wondering, while presenting in my paper, how I should call these two cases.
